# What is the better wat ro create admin role in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, database, admin, roles

I want to create simple SPA with admin-panel. I did panel and fronted part. Now I have two solutions way:

- Use enum type of row in database: $table->enum('role', ['user', 'admin]);
- Create another 'roles' table and insert there: 'user' and 'admin'
  **Which is the better way and why?**

Comment: Rather than recreate the wheel, why not investigate and use an existing community package such a [`Spatie roles and permissions`](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/role-permissions) or [`Laratrust`](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/). Your app will likely need more than just the concept of a `role` and these packages provide most of that functionality.

Comment: Yeah. you right. I tried use some packages like Orchid to get admin-panel, but there were some solutions that i doesn't like. F.e: Picture:: facade that return just a string of path, no file resource. And now I think to learn to do little features by myself to understand it clearly

Comment: There is no harm in researching how to do these things yourself and it is an excellent way to improve your skillset. Making use of small packages such as those from `Spatie` is different to simply using a fully baked admin panel though. Lots of people create their own admin panel as it provides more flexibility, but will utilise existing packages for specific functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always try to go for the simplest, clearest solution. As long a you only have 2 roles, admin and user, and a customer can only have one role, the first solution is much easier.

Defining a new table would give unwanted complexity, and also to ask for each user it's role from a different table could be timeconsuming.

Perhaps if you have more roles, and a user can have multiple roles, the second solution is more clear.

Comment: First solution is much simpler compare to second one

Comment: yes I stated the same